# I want to uninstall Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Windows 7 laptop and I am trying to uninstall it but when I insert the Ubuntu disk I can not find any uninstall options.

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall Ubuntu, there's a procedure to follow not to render your computer unbootable. You will need a Windows repair disc or installation disc or some other similar disc to fix your MBR.

1. Create a Windows repair disc. Boot Windows, search for **System Repair Disc**. Follow instructions.
2. Boot Ubuntu and backup your files on the Linux partition if there's anything you do not want to loose.
3. Boot from the repair disc. Choose the **command prompt** option and run `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot`. At this point Ubuntu is no longer bootle even though everything is there except the bootloader.
4. Reboot your PC. It should boot directly into Windows.
5. Recover the space occupied by the Ubuntu partions. Right-click **My Computer** select **Manage**, then **Disk Management**. Delete the Ubuntu partitions (main and swap). Then, either create a new partition in their place or enlarge your current partition. What is possible and how you do this depends on your current partition table. The easiest and safest way is to simply create a new partition instead of the two left behind by Ubuntu.

That's it.